# Can we execute separate process with another main function randomly in spring boot application?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I need to perform some import exercise into DB **randomly(not scheduled)**.
For these m using existing application API's and repository to insert data.
do we have any option to start another main function in existing running server to perform this task?

right now i have to start another complete application to perform this task separately.

Comment: you can use @Async functionality of spring boot for marking functions which will executed in an Asynchronous way on a different thread !

Answer (score 0):

You can have an api exposed which calls your function performing the import exercise.You can expose this api in any existing spring boot project and call that api at any time

Comment: that i already implemented, but i am looking for the way to run it from command line anytime directly without exposing any API.

Comment: I would not recommend this but what you could do is attach a signal handler and call your function whenever it receives a signal(like sigusr1, not sigkill!)

Comment: is there any drawback calling from another main method?

Comment: You cannot have two main methods in an application. If it has to main methods, you have to specify the class containing the main method in maven while compiling

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most